# How to loop through an unknown sized tensor and do tensor operations on its elements?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensor, loss-function

I am currently working on a neural network that takes some inputs and returns 2 outputs. I used 2 outputs in a regression problem where they both are 2 coordinates, X and Y.
My problem doesn't need X and Y values but angle it is facing which is atan2(y,x).

I am trying to to create a custom keras metric and a loss function that does a atan2 operation between the elements of the predicted tensor and true tensor so as to better train the network on my task.

The shape of the output tensor in metric is [?, 2] and I want to do a function where I can loop through the tensor and apply atan2(tensor[itr, 1], tensor[itr, 0]) on it to get an array of another tensors.

1. I have tried using tf.slit and tf.slice
2. I don't want to convert it into a numpy array and back to tensorflow due to performance reasons.
3. I have tried to get the shape of tensors using tensor.get_shape().as_list() and iterate through it.

```py
self.model.compile(loss="mean_absolute_error",
               optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.01),
               metrics=[vect2d_to_angle_metric])

# This is the function i want to work on
def vect2d_to_angle_metric(y_true, y_predicted):
    print("y_true = ", y_true)
    print("y_predicted = ", y_predicted)
    print("y_true shape = ", y_true.shape())
    print("y_predicted shape = ", y_predicted.shape())
```

The print out of the above function being

```py
y_true =  Tensor("dense_2_target:0", shape=(?, ?), dtype=float32)
y_predicted =  Tensor("dense_2/BiasAdd:0", shape=(?, 2), dtype=float32)
y_true shape =  Tensor("metrics/vect2d_to_angle_metric/Shape:0", shape=(2,), dtype=int32)
y_predicted shape =  Tensor("metrics/vect2d_to_angle_metric/Shape_1:0", shape=(2,), dtype=int32)
```

Python pseudo-code of the functionality I want to apply to the tensorflow function

```py
 def evaluate(self):
        mean_array = []
        for i in range(len(x_test)):
            inputs = x_test[i]
            prediction = self.model.getprediction(i)
            predicted_angle = np.arctan2(result[i][1], result[i][0])
            real_angle = np.arctan2(float(self.y_test[i][1]), float(self.y_test[i][0]))
            mean_array.append(([abs(predicted_angle - real_angle)]/real_angle) * 100)
            i += 1
```

I expect to slide the 2 sides of the tensor [i][0] and [i][1] and to a tf.atan2() function on both of them and finally make another tensor out of them so as to follow with other calculations and pass the custom loss.